# Filling array with asterisks based on a random word

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a new programmer, so sorry if the question is dumb. 
I am trying to fill an array with asterisks based on a word that is randomly selected. Language is Java.

```
public void fillArray(){

    int wordLength = randomWord.length();

    arrayOfAsterisks = new String[wordLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfAsterisks.length; i++)
    {
        arrayOfAsterisks[i] = " " + "*";            
    }
}
```

Comment: Which programming language is this? Please try and use a suitable tag ...

Comment: Java, sorry about not posting that, slipped my mind. will update the post also, thanks.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: What is the expected result? How does it differ from the actual result?

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. The mistake was actually in the Tester file and the above piece of code worked as I intended!. Thanks again!